# 'module' object has no attribute 'format'

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I tried to display the number with more precise digits.

```
import string    
print string.format(" %.5f", 0.5)
```

But this one threw me an error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'format'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`%`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#string-formatting-operations) operator or [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format):

```
>>> "%.5f" % 0.5
'0.50000'
>>> "{:.5f}".format(0.5)
'0.50000'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you falsetru! The operation is much clearer than mine. But is there something wrong with the usage of string.format?

Comment: @user3023475, There's no `format` function in `string` module.